# Indirect speech for past tense

Tags: past-tense, spoken-english, past-perfect, reported-speech

What would be the indirect speech for the sentence given below.

The teacher said,"she was sick yesterday".

Which one is correct.

1. The teacher said that she was sick the previous day.
2. The teacher said that she had been sick the previous day.

Comment: There is no such thing as indirect speech as far as grammar is concerned. Did you mean *passive voice*?

Comment: @FeliniusRex; There, of course, is indirect speech; passive voice is totally different.

Comment: @RamPillai Not in grammar there isn't.

Comment: @FeliniusRex; https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech_2; Direct & Indirect Speech is known by another name 'reported speech'.

Comment: @RamPillai Ok, it exists in the UK. Happy trails.